# Release plugin error - no POM in this directory

Tags: maven, release

I am trying to use the maven release plugin but I have an error that prevents me to use it.

My folder structure:

```
+root
    +parent
        pom.xml
    +projectA
        pom.xml
    +projectB
        pom.xml
    pom.xml
```

root/parent/pom.xml

```
<project ...>
    <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>throttling</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    ...

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:hg:https://code.google.com/***</connection>
    </scm>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>deployment</id>
            ...
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>deployment</id>
            ...
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

root/pom.xml

```
<project ...>
    <artifactId>throttling-modules</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>throttling</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>projectA</module>
        <module>projectB</module>
    </modules>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:hg:https://code.google.com/***</connection>
    </scm>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>deployment</id>
            ...
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>deployment</id>
            ...
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

root/projectA/pom.xml

```
<project ...>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <artifactId>thr-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>thr-common</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    ...
</project>
```

I executed the command 'mvn release:prepare' that ran fine.

After that I executed the 'mvn release:perform' but I got the next error message
(mvn release:perform -Dusername=???? -Dpassword=????? -DconnectionUrl=scm:hg:https://code.google.com/???):

```
[INFO] Checking out the project to perform the release ...
[INFO] Removing D:\work\throttling\code_google\***\throttling\parent\target\checkout
[INFO] EXECUTING: cmd.exe /X /C "hg clone -r release_parent-1.1 https://***:***@code.google.com/*** D:\work\throttling\code_google\***\throttling\parent\target\checkout"
[INFO] EXECUTING: cmd.exe /X /C "hg locate"
[INFO] Executing goals 'deploy'...
[WARNING] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (D:\work\throttling\code_google\***\throttling\parent\target\checkout). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
```

The folder structure in throttling\parent\target

```
+throttling\parent\target
    +checkout
        +throttling
            +parent
            +projectA
            +projectB
```

Thanks,
V.

Comment: have you run mvn release:perform in root folder right?

Comment: Hi emelendez, I assume first I have to release the parent project to a non snapshot version and after that I can release the rest of the projects. Or am I mistaken? Thanks, V.

Comment: I need to know which pom.xml (root or parent) has modules section in xml. Could you confirm that?

Comment: Hi emendelez, thanks again! The modules section is in the root/pom.xml. V.

Comment: Thanks to provide the information, first of all you need to remove -SNAPSHOT and then run **mvn release:perform** in root project

Comment: Hi emelendez, I forgot to mention that the pom.xmls attached are in the state before the mvn release:prepare (that's why the snapshot version). The prepare can change the version to a non-snaphot version (e.g. 1.0) but I have problems with the perform. I assume I have to increase the version of the parent first and afterwards the rest of the projects (as I have to use the 1.0 parent in the module and child poms). Am I right? Thanks again, V.

Comment: parent is also in your root's poml.xml as a module? I don't think so, then you upgrade that version point to new veraion of parent commit and finally run release:perform

Comment: Hi emelendez, I could solve the problem, thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem in the end, the path of the parent pom had to be defined in the parent pom XML.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>perform</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <pomFileName>parent/pom.xml</pomFileName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This works wonderfully... but why? my pom file name doesn't match what is in this config. After hours of trying to resolve this (using non-standard pom location/name) this was the only thing that worked (using this config exactly as shown above)

Comment: Hi Noremac, actually I cannot answer and it seems strange to me why the path of the parent pom has to be set. I would be curious what the answer is too.

Comment: Another question, how did you get this specific config? Was there a site you found it on?

Comment: Luckily google.com was very friendly and helped me :) Actually I don't know where I found this information but I was reaaaly happy...